# How can I generate JWT token using HMAC? How is the signature created?

Tags: python, jwt, base64url, hmacsha256

I went to this website https://jwt.io/#debugger-io
Here I took the given sample info and passed it to my code.

But the encoded information that I got is not matching what is given on the website.
Since I am doing something wrong here, I am not able to generate the signature in a valid format.

I need to make a program for JWT verification without using PyJWT types libraries.

Here is my code

```py
import base64
import hmac
header = {"alg": "HS256", "typ": "JWT"}
payload = {"sub": "1234567890", "name": "John Doe", "iat": 1516239022}
header = base64.urlsafe_b64encode(bytes(str(header), 'utf-8'))
payload = base64.urlsafe_b64encode(bytes(str(payload), 'utf-8'))
print(header)
print(payload)
signature = hmac.new(bytes('hi', 'utf-8'), header + b'.' + payload, digestmod='sha256').hexdigest()
print(signature)
```

Outputs
[image]

Answer (score 1):

There are 3 things that need to be changed in your code.

1. your header and payload are not valid JSON. If you decode the result of your Base64 encoded header `eydhbGcnOiAnSFMyNTYnLCAndHlwJzogJ0pXVCd9` you get

> {'alg': 'HS256', 'typ': 'JWT'}

but it should be (with `"`instead of `'`)

> {"alg": "HS256", "typ": "JWT"}

2. the function `base64.b64encode` produces an output that can still contain '='. The padding has to be removed.
3. You create the signature with `.hexdigest()`, which produces a hex-ascii string. Instead you need to use `.digest()` to get binary output and then Base64URL encode the result.

The code below is a corrected version of your code which produces a JWT string that can be verified on https://jwt.io.

```
import base64
import hmac

header = '{"alg":"HS256","typ":"JWT"}'
payload = '{"sub":"1234567890","name":"John Doe","iat":1516239022}'

header = base64.urlsafe_b64encode(bytes(str(header), 'utf-8')).decode().replace("=", "")
payload = base64.urlsafe_b64encode(bytes(str(payload), 'utf-8')).decode().replace("=", "")
print(header)
print(payload)
signature = hmac.new(bytes('hi', 'utf-8'), bytes(header + '.' + payload, 'utf-8'), digestmod='sha256').digest()
sigb64 = base64.urlsafe_b64encode(bytes(signature)).decode().replace("=", "")
print(sigb64)
token = header + '.' + payload + '.' + sigb64
print(token)
```

As a sidenote: The secret that you use to create the HMAC should have a length of [at least 256 bits](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/31473/what-size-should-the-hmac-key-be-with-sha-256), even if the very short key is accepted. Some libs enforce a minimum key length.